# Automatically resize li and add space between them (rtMedia masonry)

Tags: css, responsive-design, resize, gallery

I'm using the rtMedia plugin to display a masonry gallery with images uploaded by users. My question is: how can I add space between the images to distribute them evenly inside the `ul`? When I add `margin`, the `li` elements aren't displayed next to each other anymore (the third one appears in the next row).  But when I add `padding` the div inside the `li` appears larger than the rest.

I added the following CSS code to resize the `li` elements automatically.

```css
.rtmedia-container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.rtmedia-container ul {
  display: table-row;
}
.rtmedia-container ul li {
  display: table-cell;
  max-width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="rtmedia-container">
  <div id="rtm-gallery-title-container">...</div>
  <ul class="rtmedia-list">
    <li class="rtmedia-list-item">
      <div class="rtmedia-gallery-item-actions">...</div>
      <a class="rtmedia-list-item-a"> ... </a>
    </li>
    <li class="rtmedia-list-item">
      <div class="rtmedia-gallery-item-actions">...</div>
      <a class="rtmedia-list-item-a"> ... </a>
    </li>
    <li class="rtmedia-list-item">
      <div class="rtmedia-gallery-item-actions">...</div>
      <a class="rtmedia-list-item-a"> ... </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I just noticed that the gallery is overlaping the div (rtm-gallery-title-container) in every browser except for Firefox. Does someone know how to solve this problem?

I also had to add "position: relative" to the div .rtmedia-container, because the gallery hasn't been displayed on the right position in other browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `border-collapse:separate` + `border-spacing`

#### Snippet

```css
.rtmedia-container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed; /* optional  */
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 5px;
  /*demo */
  border: 1px dashed red
}
.rtmedia-container ul {
  display: table-row;
}
.rtmedia-container ul li {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 33%;
}
.rtmedia-container ul li img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height:auto;
  display:block
}
```

```html
<div class="rtmedia-container">
  <ul class="rtmedia-list">
    <li class="rtmedia-list-item">
      <div class="rtmedia-gallery-item-actions">...</div>
      <a class="rtmedia-list-item-a">
        <img src="//lorempixel.com/700/300" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="rtmedia-list-item">
      <div class="rtmedia-gallery-item-actions">...</div>
      <a class="rtmedia-list-item-a">
        <img src="//lorempixel.com/700/300" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="rtmedia-list-item">
      <div class="rtmedia-gallery-item-actions">...</div>
      <a class="rtmedia-list-item-a">
        <img src="//lorempixel.com/700/300" />
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```